# why is the images not showing in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

my code is supposed to show a picture depending on witch pic it lands on in the random function.

this is my html

```
 <div>
    <h2>Joureur 0:</h2>

    <div id="MainJoueur0"></div>         
 </div>
```

then in my .ts i did this

```
afficherCarteJoueurZero() {

        document.getElementById('MainJoueur0').innerHTML = '<div></div>';

        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            let img = new Image(90, 130);
            img.src = "assets/images/" + this.sorte + "_" + this.valeur + ".gif";
            document.getElementById('MainJoueur0').appendChild(img);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are there a good reason to not use a more "angular way" like `<img *ngFor="let i of [0,1] [src]="assets/images/" + this.sorte + "_" + this.valeur + ".gif">` ? Using javascript to add an image is not "Angular way"

Comment: am new to angular so i dont know all the syntax but i will try that way. Thanks @Eliseo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorte and valeur is `array`, you need get string by `index` as

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            let img = new Image(90, 130);
            img.src = "assets/images/" + this.sorte[i] + "_" + this.valeur[i] + ".gif";
            document.getElementById('MainJoueur0').appendChild(img);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img.src = "assets/images/" + this.sorte + "_" + this.valeur + ".gif";
```

this.sorte and this.valeur are arrays, shouldn't you pick an index from them?

Comment: ohh how do you do that

Comment: Check Hien Nguyen answer he implemented, what I suggested.